# Is there a way to use Sass with css module together?

Tags: node-sass, css-modules

So far i have been using scss / sass with create react app, so i was downloading the node-sass package. But I have just discovered CSS module, I like the principle, and I would like to know if it is possible to use both at the same time, ie to have "MyComponent.module.scss" files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can make files with the extension ".module.scss" to use SCSS and CSS Module at the same time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can just rename

> MyComponent.css

To

> MyComponent.module.scss

And use

`'import classes from './MyComponent.module.scss'`

```
<div className={classes.yourClass}> Lorem </div>
```

Or

```
<div className={classes['your-class']}> Lorem </div>
```